# passing arguments to JQuery in grails

Tags: jquery, grails

i have [radioGroup](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.1/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html) in my GSP :

```
<g:each in="${questions}" var='qu'>
<span id="qEnglish-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="questions.qEnglish.label" default="Q English" /></span>

                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="qEnglish-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${qu}" field="qEnglish"/></span>

<g:radioGroup class='radioGroup'   values="['good','med','bad']"   name="radio${radioName++}" labels="['good','med','bad']"> ${it.label} : ${it.radio} </g:radioGroup>
```

i added `change` listener to call AJAX in the jquery code as below , i need to pass arguments suppose to come `qu.id` from the `each` and the `value` of the `radioButton` to the below Jquery code instead of the values of `qId,qAns` , how this could be done.

Jquery code:

```
$('.radioGroup').on('change',function(){

var args=JSON.stringify({qId:'tt1',qAns: 'aa1'});
$.ajax({
    url:'${createLink(controller:'questions' , action:'tempSaveAjax')}',
    type:'POST' ,
    data:{ json:args }, 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert (" done " );
            },
    error: function(data,  textStatus,  errorThrown) { // Handle errors here
        alert ("erroooor : " + textStatus/*data.responseText*/);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Please clarify where the arguments are supposed to come from. Are they coming from the radioGroup's selection or are they predetermined and set when the GSP is rendered into HTML?

Comment: i edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is really just a jQuery question. You already have what you need to grab the answer, but you'll need to allow for a way to grab the question easily. I think an data attribute will do the trick, which would be something like this:

```
<g:radioGroup class='radioGroup' 'data-question-id'="${qu.id}" values="['good','med','bad']"   name="radio${radioName++}" labels="['good','med','bad']"> ${it.label} : ${it.radio} </g:radioGroup>
```

I'm not entirely sure of that attribute syntax. But, then you can easily grab both of the arguments you need...

```
$('.radioGroup').on('change',function(){

var args=JSON.stringify({qId: $(this).attr('data-question-id'), qAns: $(this).val()});
$.ajax({
    url:'${createLink(controller:'questions' , action:'tempSaveAjax')}',
    type:'POST' ,
    data:{ json:args }, 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert (" done " );
            },
    error: function(data,  textStatus,  errorThrown) { // Handle errors here
        alert ("erroooor : " + textStatus/*data.responseText*/);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: thanks the `data` attribute did the magic , appreciate your help.